# Java Iterate over Map values

Tags: java, json, dictionary, arraylist

I have a problem. I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "Market":"USDT",
   "Coin":"BTC",
   "Period":"1h",
   "EmergencyPerc":-25,
   "TakeProfitPerc":1.2,
   "ProtectiveOrdersEnabled":"no",
   "EMACrossMarginPerc":0.08,
   "EMABuySellPeriod":"5m",
   "EMABuySellNameLow":"EMA5",
   "EMABuySellNameHigh":"EMA20",
   "EMAUnfreezePeriod":"1h",
   "EMAUnfreezeNameLow":"EMA20",
   "EMAUnfreezeNameHigh":"EMA200",
   "SimTemplate":"t001",
   "PriceDropSells":[
      {
         "Period":"3h",
         "Number":"4",
         "Perc":"-1.0"
      },
      {
         "Period":"1h",
         "Number":"2",
         "Perc":"-2.0"
      }
   ]
}
```

In my java class I added the following code to parse the Json to the current class as object:

```
public class AgentStrategy {

    private String market;
    private String coin;
    private String period;
    private double emergencyPerc;
    private double takeProfitPerc;
    private String protectiveOrdersEnabled;
    private double EMACrossMarginPerc;
    private String EMABuySellPeriod;
    private String EMABuySellNameLow;
    private String EMABuySellNameHigh;
    private String EMAUnfreezePeriod;
    private String EMAUnfreezeNameLow;
    private String EMAUnfreezeNameHigh;
    private String simTemplate;
    private ArrayList<AgentStrategyPriceDropSells> priceDropSells = new ArrayList<>();

    public AgentStrategy parseJsonToObject(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        gson.fromJson(jsonString, AgentStrategy.class);

        Map map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
        this.market = map.get("Market").toString();
        this.coin = map.get("Coin").toString();
        this.period = map.get("Period").toString();
        this.emergencyPerc = Double.parseDouble(map.get("EmergencyPerc").toString());
        this.takeProfitPerc = Double.parseDouble(map.get("TakeProfitPerc").toString());
        this.protectiveOrdersEnabled = map.get("ProtectiveOrdersEnabled").toString();
        this.EMACrossMarginPerc = Double.parseDouble(map.get("EMACrossMarginPerc").toString());
        this.EMABuySellPeriod = map.get("EMABuySellPeriod").toString();
        this.EMABuySellNameLow = map.get("EMABuySellNameLow").toString();
        this.EMABuySellNameHigh = map.get("EMABuySellNameHigh").toString();
        this.EMAUnfreezePeriod = map.get("EMAUnfreezePeriod").toString();
        this.EMAUnfreezeNameLow = map.get("EMAUnfreezeNameLow").toString();
        this.EMAUnfreezeNameHigh = map.get("EMAUnfreezeNameHigh").toString();
        this.simTemplate = map.get("SimTemplate").toString();


        // PRICE DROP SELLS
        Map priceDropSellsMap = (Map) map.get("PriceDropSells");
        // ???

        return this;
    }

    private class PriceDropSell {

        private String period;
        private String number;
        private double perc;

    }
}
```

The function should return a full filled Object, but I am struggling with the `ArrayList<PriceDropSell>`. The problem is that I have no idea how to store the `PriceDropSells` from my JSON as `ArrayList<PriceDropSell>`. Every field gets stored in the class AgentStrategy, except the PriceDropSell. How can I parse that part to an ArrayList?

Comment: So, `map.get("PriceDropSells")` is an array, what is inside this array?

Comment: The array looks like this: `[{Period=4h, Number=4, Perc=-1.0}, {Period=1h, Number=2, Perc=-2.0}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all the map stuff. Gson will parse directly into the object. But make sure the names match:

```
class Test
{
    private class PriceDropSell {
        private String Period;
        private String Number;
        private double Perc;
    }
    public class AgentStrategy {
        private String Market;
        private String Coin;
        private String Period;
        private double EmergencyPerc;
        private double TakeProfitPerc;
        private String ProtectiveOrdersEnabled;
        private double EMACrossMarginPerc;
        private String EMABuySellPeriod;
        private String EMABuySellNameLow;
        private String EMABuySellNameHigh;
        private String EMAUnfreezePeriod;
        private String EMAUnfreezeNameLow;
        private String EMAUnfreezeNameHigh;
        private String SimTemplate;
        private ArrayList<PriceDropSell> PriceDropSells;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path_to_json_file));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AgentStrategy agent = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, AgentStrategy.class);
        
        System.out.println(agent.PriceDropSells.get(0).Perc);
    }
}
```

Comment: AgentStrategy needs to be a Array, because I can have multiple in 1 AgentStrategy!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I'm not sure what you mean. Does the JSON file have an array of `AgentStrategy` objects or do you have multiple JSON sources?

Comment: Sorry, the JSON has 1 object called `AgentStrategy` with multiple `PriceDropSell` objects. So I want those to be stored in an `ArrayList<PriceDropSell>`.

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer to be an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. The reason my names with with lowercase was, because at my current study, I learn that the first letter must be lowercase, so I tried that and then remap everything, because my father did everything in CamelCase xD. But thanks for your help!

Comment: YW. If you want the names to be lower case see: [GSON - Deserialize case insensitive field name (no definite case pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105677)

Answer (score -1):

Why not inspect what the actual object for "PriceDropSells" is ? Just get that property without any casts and check with a debugger it's type:

Object priceDropSellsMap = map.get("PriceDropSells");

I suppose it should be an array or a List.

Comment: Thanks, it's an array. What would be the best way to parse it to an arraylist with the class `PriceDropSells`?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Are you familiar with [jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API))?  This is usually the recommended solution on SO.